Parabolic SAR Calc. -> Short, UTHR example (Tradingview)
I'm calculating the falling Parabolic SAR (SAR) in trading view on UTHR's chart, going back to UTHR's first ever recorded trading session (06/17/1999) on the chart.
Falling SAR = Prior SAR −[Prior AF(Prior SAR-Prior EP)]
Where, AF = Acceleration factor (0.02 in this case, to a MAX of 0.2)
Prior EP = Prior extreme point.
(I assume the person reading this understands the SAR calculation, so I didn't want to go into full detail on the extreme point and other things, so I can summarize this post.)
Basically, my question is fairly simple - I understand how to calculate the SAR values, but for the SAR#2, I'm not sure how they get the same value as the SAR #1.
I attached my calculations of SAR#1 to SAR#8, and the values Trading View provides. My answers are the same as Trading Views' (when rounded), but I didn't understand the calculation for SAR#2, so I left it as "???" and I just took it to be 7.25, and then used that 7.25 for my SAR#3 Calculation, and so on.
So just wondering how they got 7.25 for both SAR#1 and SAR#2.
I see they got SAR#1 from the 1st sessions high, but for them to get it for the SAR#2, I wasn't sure how they got that, since Prior EP should be $6.00 (as my photo shows), and Prior AF should be 0.02,
so (from my understanding) SAR#2=7.25-[0.02(7.25-6.00)]=$7.225, but that's not the value for SAR#2 on TradingView (though it is the value we get for SAR#3.)
If anyone can help me out with this would be great! Thanks
SAR CALCULATIONS:
The high of the first session ever recorded in UTHR’s daily chart (06/17/1999) is 7.25.
SAR #1=7.25
SAR #2 = ???
= $7.25
SAR #3 = $7.25 - [0.02 ($7.25 - $6.00)]
= $7.225
SAR #4 = $7.225 - [0.02 ($7.225 - $6.00)]
= $7.2005
SAR #5 = $7.2005 - [0.02 ($7.2005 - $6.00)]
=$7.17649
SAR #6 = $7.17649 - [0.02 ($7.17649 - $6.00)]
= $7.1529602
SAR #7 = $7.1529602 - [0.04 ($7.1529602 - $5.75)]
= $7.09684
NOTE:
Here the “Prior EP” decreased to $5.75 (we hit a new low of $5.75 on the prior day - See photo).
Here the “Prior AF” increased to 0.04 (0.02+0.02), since we reached a new extreme low in the prior session.
SAR #8 = $7.09684 - [0.04 ($7.09684 - $5.75)]
= $7.04297
TRADING VIEW SAR VALUES:
SAR #1=$7.25
SAR #2=$7.25
SAR #3=$7.23
SAR #4=$7.20
SAR #5=$7.18
SAR #6=$7.15
SAR #7=$7.10
SAR #8=$7.04

